# A bug with netty to upload file through http protocol

Tags: file, http, upload, netty

I don't know if this is really a bug, but I did encounter it.

**It appeared when I used HttpPostRequestDecoder to assist me in accepting a file uploaded via HTTP.**

When the file name is **all English letters or numbers**, everything is fine; But once the file name **contains** Chinese, Korean, Japanese and other **non-English characters**, an "**ErrorDataDecoderException**" error is thrown.

I checked for a long time, and finally looked at the source code, and found that when the file name contains other languages, the content body part is:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name = "file"; filename = "c73b1345ab18deeef6cdb220d62fc976我是汉字.jpg"; filename* = "UTF-8''c73b1345ab18deeef6cdb220d62fc976%E6%88%91%E6%98%AF%E6%B1%89%E5%AD%97.jpg"
```

When it is a pure English part, the content body is:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name = "file"; filename = "6e3f8201c976de67aae094c72634f75e.jpg"
```

Obviously, they are not the same, so when I replaced it with separation based on lines, everything worked fine (that's a new Class I wrote myself).

So is Netty using a ‘;’ to separation content body? That leads to this error. If not, how did this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug that was recently fixed:

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/10089

Please upgrade to latest Netty version

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. That is the answer. And new I can write new code!